# Raspberry Pi uses different theme for programs when launched from LXTerminal rather than Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am new to Qt and programming in general.
I have made my first GUI application in QtCreator, and when the program is run from QtCreator itself, it uses the current LXDE theme my Pi is running for all the buttons/sliders etc which looks great.
When run from LXterminal however (which I need to do because the program requires root access) the program uses a different theme which looks much more outdated.

Is there a way of making programs run from LXTerminal use the current theme of the Pi?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't need root access. Maybe some small part of your program does, and that small part should be separated out into e.g. a suid-root executable, etc. Most likely you don't need root access, but an adjustment of permissions on the device nodes you're trying to access, etc.

The root access is why the theming doesn't work. The root account is not configured with any themes, because it's not supposed to be an interactive account where you run gui applications.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The program requires access to the Raspberry Pi GPIO through the use of WiringPi which requires root access. I was actually able to make the program use a theme similar to the one used in Qt Designer called "CleanLooks" using the line QApplication::setStyle("CleanLooks") and this theme is applied to the program when running from the terminal with root access. Not an ideal solution but looks a lot better than the standard theme the root account provides!

Comment: @StuckInALoop With WiringPi you should use a modern kernel, and access gpio via `/dev/gpiomem`, with permissions set so that your executable has access to that device node. This needs no root access. For the most part, code that "needs" root is broken and is a result of not understanding how to do it otherwise.